# Where can one find guidance from a teacher next year in 2018?

Tags: meditation, insight, retreat, guidance, stages

Where on Earth or online are future retreats or classes for an insight practitioner to get Dhamma guidance and/or guidance through some version of the stages of insight meditation?

Are there teachers who might guide an insight practitioner on a one on one basis, given the right situation?

Answer (score 3):

Best and proper way is to approach and ask personal, after having spend a good time next him and have observed his virtues, Nyom Lowbrown.

It's in dependency of assossiation with admirable friends, that one gaines right view. Of course the condition to meet such is a matter of upanissayapaccayena (strong condition causes) and not possible to buy and demand.

So keep always in mind: [Better to Give than to Consume](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/bettertogive_en.html). Having not the right attitude and behaviour, one, like many and most, would just meet poor business in Dhamma and Juwel-thieves of many kinds.

People who are really into Dhamma have neither dates nor calenders, but always open doors for those seeing them and having the condition to enter. For those always right in front and near. Someone demand, consume... no way to meet, enter and learn, or being haunted by spirits when enter without a clean and honest mind.

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma and not meant for commercial purpose or other low wordily gains by means of trade and exchange.]*

Comment: Sounds like you have some inside information on the subject.

Comment: It's not good to seek after something to consume at first place, Nyom @Lowbrow , again. Such an attitude cut one off to be guided to look for oneself inside to gain insight and know valid. This costumer attitude is importand to be abounded at first place and its not so easy but place for vipassana already to practice giving and lowering one self on a gross level.

Comment: Ok but that's what a dana based retreat is for isn't it? You expect student's to be this way or that way or already knowing what is what? What's wrong with consuming  The Dhamma of a good teacher and the teacher performing good karma?

Comment: Do as you like, Lowbrow. If thinking Dhamma can be gained by trade, try it. As my person does neither have nor desire student, relay on the Buddhas way of teaching and don't listen to my person, but it's free and you can not give any reward back: anupubbi-sikkha [A Gradual Training](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/ptf/dhamma/index_en.html) to the giver. See also:

Comment: [Respect, Confidence and Patient](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,8233.0.html), traders might take money or other reward before or after instead and that might be ok for consumer, yet no success in that way, Nyom @Lowbrow . Dana-based... whats that then cheating, calling deal dana. Nobody who teaches Dhamma takes anything for it or expect, in that way you got already in dept torward liberation.

Comment: When I say "trade" I don't think I'm being as literal as you are , IDK.

Comment: A teacher says come meditate and the students comes and meditates there's no evil exchanged on a dana basis. There is dana taken only when there is a need. I really wasn't trying to get that deep into it. What do you think of places like "Spirit Rock" that claims the student must pay for the "retreat" but not the teacher?

Answer (score 2):

The oral study system, mukkhapatha, still going on at pa-auk monastery.

By this study system, you can practice every meditation step by step.

The teacher will teach you just a bit per meeting for easily to memorize and to practice.

This monastery may not give you an insight meditation first, because jhana is very important for an advance insight meditation. So, pa auk teacher will teach you jhana, first. After that you will ready for an advance insight meditation.

http://www.paaukforestmonastery.org/rules.htm